# Is there a way to convert a web element found by selenium into an integer? (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, type-conversion

```
prices = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'a-price-whole')
for i in range(len(prices)):
    num = float(prices[i].text)
    total_prices.append(num)
```

I'm trying to convert the elements found on a website by selenium into an integer or float in python but each time I get an error that says either "num = int(prices[i].text) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''" or "num = float(prices[i].text) ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''" when I try to convert the received elements into a float. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: what is all of the text that you get when you just print out it out with `.text` because you may have to clean the text output to only contain numbers

Comment: It turns out that I have a bunch of None's in the output, however when I try to filter them out only some of them get filtered when I use: `act_prices = [j for j in temp_prices if j is not None]` which makes me think some of the outputted '' aren't actually Nones but I don't know what they are...

Comment: What site are you trying to get these items from?

Comment: I was trying to get the prices off of Amazon. I managed to find a way to avoid those weird spots in the collected data but copying the valid data into a different list. I just wish it was easier to get prices off of websites because I think those weird spots might have data that I will be missing...

Comment: if you could provide an example of the items we might be better able to help, but as it currently is written it is hard to give any more additional advice

Comment: You need to post a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While fetching the prices, there is a comma(,) in every text, that's why you are getting that error. You have to replace that comma:

```
for i in range(len(prices)):
    num = prices[i].text.replace("," , "")
    total_prices.append(float(num))

print(total_prices)
```